# Variable disappears when I filter the Database Table

Tags: java

I am making a library System where the user can search and filter the data in the database. My code is now filtering the table however when I start to type the variable txtNo disappears. I cannot identify what is the problem.

```
 private void txtSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
        try { 
            String sql = "SELECT txtNo, txtTitle, txtAuthor, txtGenre, txtLexile, txtPoints FROM LibrarySystemDatabase WHERE txtNo like '%"+txtSearch.getText()+"%' "
                    + "OR txtTitle like '%"+txtSearch.getText()+"%'"
                    + "OR txtAuthor like '%"+txtSearch.getText()+"%'"
                    + "OR txtGenre like '%"+txtSearch.getText()+"%'"
                    + "OR txtLexile like '%"+txtSearch.getText()+"%'"
                    + "OR txtPoints like '%"+txtSearch.getText()+"%'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement (sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            tblTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            tblTable.removeColumn(tblTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));
        } catch(Exception e) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does removeColumn method do ?

Comment: removes the column when the input in the txtSearch does not meet the keywords

Comment: Try running your code by commenting the removeColumn method. See if the issue still occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit seems to be your `removeColumn` method. Try removing it and try.